# Calling php function with exact variables

Tags: php, mysql, function

Lets say we have function that gets 5 variables.

```
function func($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5 ) 
{
  if ($var1==1)
  {
    work with $var2, $var3
  }
  if ($var1==2)
  {
    work with $var4, $var5
  }
}
```

For example, we want to call this function like that: `func(1,$var2, $var3)` (without unused variables) or like that `func(2,$var4, $var5)`.

Is it possible? How to send exact variables to php function?

**UPDATE**
Based on @marcus's answer I modified my function.

```
<?

function GenerateTopNav($current, $lang, $db)
{
    $result=$db->query("SELECT `id`, `parent`, $lang FROM `nav` WHERE `menu`='1'");
        while ($row=$result->fetch_object()){
            echo '<a ';
            if($row->id==$current)
            echo 'class="active"';
            echo 'href="index.php?id='.$row->id.'">'.$row->$lang.'</a> | ';
    }

function GenerateLeftNav($parent, $level, $lang, $db){  
         $q = $db->query("SELECT `id`, `$lang` AS name FROM nav WHERE parent = '$parent' AND `menu`='2'");
          if($level > 0 && $q->num_rows > 0){
          echo "\n<ul>\n";
          }
          while($row=$q->fetch_object()){
                echo "<li>";
                echo '<a href="?page=' . $row->id . '">' . $row->name . '</a>';
                //display this level's children
                GenerateLeftNav($row->id, $level+1, $lang, $db);
                echo "</li>\n\n";
            }
          if($level > 0 &&  $q->num_rows > 0){
                echo "</ul>\n";
            }
          }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to combine these into one function?  It's much better to keep them separate, IMO.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel: Did you downvote all the answers?

Comment: @Tural: Well, that I certainly agree with. The question was unclear and is now even more so after your major edit.

Comment: This is not a clear question.

Comment: The answer all just copy-paste all the bad practice in the question instead of showing a different way. You have made your code much worse with the edit, it's also totally broken and has loads of problems. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you even need to specify 4 variables? You're basically saying specify a type and then 2 input variables for that type, so if there will always be 3 variables, just do the follow:

```
function ($type, $var1, $var2) {
    if ($type === 1) {
        // $var1 = lang and $var2 = current
        // do something with var1 and var2
    } else {
        // $var1 = parent and $var2 = level
        // do something else with var1 and var2
    }
}
```

You really don't need to spam your function with an excess number of variables that won't get used.

To be more clear: the variables don't *need* to be named appropriately, you just need to comment that if type = 1, these two variables mean these two things, and if type = 2, these two variables mean these two things and process both types accordingly.

Comment: Your code has errors and your advice is pretty bad. It goes against best practice in many ways (separation of concern, variable naming, etc.)

Comment: Please take a look at my question. I updated

Comment: Is there anything that we can remove from function or optimize

Comment: Everything can be optimized @TuralTeyyuboglu! In your code, most things need to be optimized. See my answers.

Comment: Who on earth votes something like that up??? Seriously, what is presented here is bad coding and bad advice, how can anyone vote such a thing up?

Comment: @markus: Unfortunately it doesn't let you delete accepted answers though. o.o

Answer (score 3):

You should not try to pack these things into one function. Every function should have one purpose and one purpose only. If the two tasks are very very similar, you may do it but this is not given here.

What you can and should do is breaking down your code into smaller functions which take over the similar bits. For example you could have a function called `createLinkMarkup()` which would return the HTML markup for one link element. This function you could then call from both 'mother' - functions.

But **far more important** are a few things you're doing wrong:

#### Variable and function naming

- don't call functions 'func', it's the worst thing you can do, nobody will know what that functions does
- use 'verbs' for function names, so don't call them menu either, much better: `createMenuMarkup()`
- don't ever use numbers in function names, it makes the code unreadable as well. Your second function could be called `createSubmenuMarkup()`. Such names are readable. Good for you in a couple of weeks when you have to read your code again and good for any other coder who sees your code... like us.
- In the same way, don't call variables `$var`. That's the worst thing you can do for readability (and readability = code quality). Use names that describe containers, use nouns which describe exactly what it is you're passing around. And what @animuson says is not true, you need to name your variables properly. Yes, your code will work with fuzzy names, but it won't be readable=maintainable=worthy-to-survive.

#### Usage of globals

- Do not make the db connection a global variable, in fact, do not use globals, that's a very good rule of thumb. What if you need to rename your variable, will you want to rename it in 100 different places in your code? Globals go against the best practice of encapsulation. Better ways: Pass the connection into the function, make the connection available to the class and inject it into this class, or similar to globals but much easier to manage, store the connection in a registry (registry pattern).

#### Echo from within functions

- Do not use echo within functions. Instead, store every bit of markup in a string and then return the markup. This way you can always control, what you finally render because you can manipulate it after the function has run already.

#### SQL injection

- Beware of SQL injection. You're passing the parameter `$lang` into your query, where does it come from, maybe from the querystring? If it can be manipulated by users, you're in danger. Use prepared statements or at least `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent this.

Comment: please edit my code. I want to see how must look like my code in your opinion

Comment: can you please edit my code and apply all you advices to it? Maybe, I'm not the php professional as you, but i'm trying to learn.

Comment: I'd suggest you try to make it better, test it and come back here to show us what you've got! That's how you learn, not by copy pasting it :-).

Comment: is there anything else left to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array:

```
function func($var1, $array ) 
{
  if ($var1==1)
  {
    work with $array["var2"], $array["var3"]
  }
  if ($var1==2)
  {
    work with $array["var4"], $array["var5"]
  }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
func(1, array(
  "var2" => "foo",
  "var3" => "bar"
));
```

Comment: What you're proposing is utterly unreadable code.

Answer (score 0):

for optional arguments, you can put a default value for them:

`func($val1,$val2,$val3 = 0,$val4 = 0)`

and you needn't to call them.

`func($val1,$val2)`